# open embedded pdf resource files in C++ using default windows pdf opener

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, exe

I want to include a pdf file in my .exe that is generated from a C++ code. This pdf file must be included inside the exe and not as a separate file. Also this pdf must be opened using the default app used by the user. So if I have a file called test.pdf imbedded inside the exe and the user has installed adobe reader, the pdf file should open using adobe reader. I don't want to use Qt as I am a beginner in C++ (if Qt is the only solution then please state the QT solution)

Comment: External programs can't access the PDF if it's embedded inside your .exe. You'll need to extract it to a temporary directory before passing it to the PDF viewer.

Comment: okay so how to make this extraction step then make the default program open it ? @Thomas

Comment: Use QFile::copy() and QDesktopServices::openUrl()